# Is it correct to say "running in the rain"?

Tags: prepositions

I somewhere found this sentence,
"She is running in the rain".
According to Oxford dicionary and all the other dictionaries I came across,
"In"always refers to someone or something (still or moving) that is sorrounded or enclosed by an area.And sometimes "in" refers to be present on spot but only at office or house...
So what's the logical explanation behind using "in"in this sentence??

Comment: So what does "swimming in the ocean" mean?

Comment: You can stand, run, walk, lie, sit, sing (thanks, Hachi), or leave a cake out in the rain. You'll get wet though, but you may not care.

Comment: You also have “Singing in the rain”.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129165/under-the-rain-vs-in-the-rain

Comment: @HotLicks it means being in water while having the water body around(may be).

Comment: You can run in the sunshine, as well.

Answer (score 2):

> According to Oxford dictionary and all the other dictionaries I came across, "In"always refers to someone or something (still or moving) that is surrounded or enclosed by an area.

I think you have misunderstood the dictionaries. The rain is the thing that surrounds the person who is running.

In = inside or within. (Occasionally, it is used as a short form of "into")

Comment: It's perfectly normal to use _in_ with names of weather conditions.

Comment: My laundry will dry quickly in the wind.